# Can't figure out the color of an svg element

Tags: html, css, background, svg, background-color

I have a very simple HTML page, [viewable on gh-pages](http://yasirs.github.com/toy-css-background/) with the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link href="style.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js'>
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="page">
      <div id="content">
        <div id="heatmap">
          <svg style="margin-left: 80px; color: rgb(255, 255, 255);" width="800" height="880">
            <g transform="translate(80,80)">
              <rect style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);" height="720" width="720">
              </rect>
            </g>
          </svg>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

with the following CSS:

```
body {
background-color: #FFFFFF;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
color: #FFFFFF;
}

#wrapper {
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0;
}

#page {
width: 1000px;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 40px 0px 0px 0px;
}

#content {
float: left;
width: 660px;
padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
background: #FFFFFF;
}
```

I expect the rectangle, `'svg rect'` to be the color `#FFFFFF`, or white. But it shows up as some other color. I opened it up in firebug, and it shows the computed color to be #FFFFF:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SVG graphical objects have two colours, an internal fill colour and an outline stroke color. SVG uses the fill and stroke properties to control these colours.

The html color property is mostly unused in SVG, it only operates when you use currentColor so you can do fill="currentColor" and the fill colour will become the same as the html color property.

The default value for fill is black and the default for stroke is none.

So in your case you haven't specified a fill property and you get a black filled shape.

Comment: Thanks! That explains it pretty well. I also found this [tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SVG/Tutorial/Fills_and_Strokes) at Mozilla Developer Network helpful.

Answer (score 1):

To change the colour of the rectangle, change the fill style:

```
<rect style="fill:white" width="720" height="720" />
```

Comment: Thanks, `fill:white` seems to do it, but why does it show up black otherwise? Also, what is the difference between `fill:white` and `color:rgb(255, 255, 255)`? I am sorry for the elementary questions, but I am new to CSS.

Comment: Black is the default fill style. `color` refers to text colour whereas `fill` actually refers to the fill colour of the shape (see also `stroke` for the line).

Answer (score 1):

the color is taken from the inline style in the svg. this being rgb(255,255,255) it translates to #FFFFFF without alpha value. Additionally, when you specify only a "color" value, the fill and stroke etc are computed from the generic color value. So better instead to use the svg specific attributes of fill and stroke etc. Specify the colors in full hex notation including alpha channel, instead of the rgb()..if you want to specify alpha.